# jQuery absolute positioning & border issue

Tags: jquery

I am enclosing a sample HTML5 file where I have defined 2 div's for absolute positioning alongwith a border. Both are not working. Can you please help ? I am stuck here for a long time and have tried multiple permutations, combinations of what I have seen on the web. Please note that I need to use the variables defined in this file to use with css etc.

Thanks in advance for your help. Will really appreciate if you can post the entire file after making changes to the enclosed file. Regards, sbguy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Absolute Positioning Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var A_height = 100;
var A_width = 100;
var A_top = 20;
var A_left = 20;
var B_height = 200;
var B_width = 200;
var B_top = 200;
var B_left = 200;
jQuery("#A").css({ "width": A_width, "height": A_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
jQuery("#B").css({ "width":B_width, "height":B_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
jQuery("#A").offset({top: A_top, left: A_left});
jQuery("#B").offset({top: B_top, left: B_left});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="A">
<p>HELLO A</p>
</div>
<div id="B">
<BR></BR>
<p>HELLO B</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading a little an your own wouldn't hurt. I'm pretty sure $(document).ready() is mentioned at the beginning of every jQuery tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manipulate elements that have not been created yet.  In other words, the script is executing before the divs have been added to the DOM, so jQuery can't find them.  Either move your script to the bottom or put everything in a function and pass that function to jQuery so that it gets called when the page loads (see the .ready() method).  In the example code below I just moved the script block to the end.  Everything else is essentially unchanged from your original code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Absolute Positioning Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="A">
        <p>HELLO A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="B">
        <BR></BR>
        <p>HELLO B</p>
    </div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
var A_height = 100;
var A_width = 100;
var A_top = 20;
var A_left = 20;
var B_height = 200;
var B_width = 200;
var B_top = 200;
var B_left = 200;
jQuery("#A").css({ 'width': A_width, 'height': A_height, 'border':'1px solid black'});
jQuery("#B").css({ 'width': B_width, 'height': B_height, 'border':'1px solid black'});
jQuery("#A").offset({top: A_top, left: A_left});
jQuery("#B").offset({top: B_top, left: B_left});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cMGdx/). Just you have to wrap your javascript code with [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Absolute Positioning Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var A_height = 100;
    var A_width = 100;
    var A_top = 20;
    var A_left = 20;
    var B_height = 200;
    var B_width = 200;
    var B_top = 200;
    var B_left = 200;
    jQuery("#A").css({ "width": A_width, "height": A_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
    jQuery("#B").css({ "width":B_width, "height":B_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
    jQuery("#A").offset({top: A_top, left: A_left});
    jQuery("#B").offset({top: B_top, left: B_left});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="A">
<p>HELLO A</p>
</div>
<div id="B">
<BR></BR>
<p>HELLO B</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This script works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Absolute Positioning Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 A_height = 100;
 A_width = 100;
 A_top = 20;
 A_left = 20;
 B_height = 200;
 B_width = 200;
 B_top = 200;
 B_left = 200;
$("#A").css({ "width": A_width, "height": A_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
$("#B").css({ "width":B_width, "height":B_height, "border":'1px solid black'});
$("#A").offset({top: A_top, left: A_left});
$("#B").offset({top: B_top, left: B_left});
                           });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="A">
<p>HELLO A</p>
</div>
<div id="B">
<BR></BR>

<p>HELLO B</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```